# Is there any GUI application for command rsync?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, rsync

I am currently synchronize between local folders in my computer by following command:

```
rsync -av --delete "[source]" "[destination]"
```

Now I want to do this via GUI. so, Is there any **GUI** available for Ubuntu which works similar as by command `rsync`? and How can I install it?

Comment: You ca use `gadmin-rsync` or `grsync` as a graphical front end of rsync.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, there is available **[Grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/)** GUI App as front end of `rsync` tool.

> **Grsync is a rsync GUI (Graphical User Interface)**

It is available on Universe repository for Ubuntu 14.04 and can be installed by following
command:

To Enable Ubuntu repository run command (or make sure that enabled from **Software & Updates**):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe"
```

**Install `Grsync` By following command:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grsync
```

---

Here is Screen-Shot of Grsync GUI Application with some steps shown below:

[image]

Source & Destination can be selected same as from `rsync`.

Also you can save different Session for future or often use.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: Use the Software Sources GUI for changing/adding Ubuntu repos (they respect the user's mirror selection). `grsync` is in `universe`, so we don't need to enable everything.

Comment: @muru you are Right But Enabling all Ubuntu Repository can be useful in future. And CLI is more suitable for such package-management (install/remove/fix).

Comment: yes, but not respecting the user's choice of mirror and simply setting archive.ubuntu is not good practice. There's a reason mirrors exist. CLI is suitable for package management, but for managing the official repos, Software Sources is the best way.

Comment: @muru ok. I've edited for Software & Updates as other choice. And if repo. already enabled than that command don't harm anything!

Answer (score 18):

I think that the most powerful application with a GUI for synchronizing is [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). You can install it via

```
sudo apt-get install unison-gtk
```

and it will allow you to sync directory locally, with mounted drives, and on the network via `ssh` connections. It detects conflicts and in that case it will ask you what to do.

[image]

It is quite easy to get started but can become very powerful if you learn how to edit the configuration files by hand; [the documentation is really good](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html). There is a command-line interface which is quite handy for scripting.

Answer (score 5):

Another GUI application for `rsync` is `luckyBackup`.

It is available in the default Debian / Ubuntu repositories.
Therefore, you could install it by

```
sudo apt-get install luckybackup
```

It is useful particularly if you are looking to use `rsync` for backing up files.