# Transfer files between two remote SSH servers

Tags: ssh, nautilus, transfer, nemo, caja

Is there an easy way to transfer files between two SSH/SFTP servers? The perfect solution would be FileZilla, but it only lets you create a connection between local and remote, but not between remote and remote.

Theoretically I could open two Nautilus windows and connect to some `ssh://server1/path/to/folder` and `ssh://server2/path/to/folder` and then just pull the files from one to the other side. My experience is that this is very unstable. Transmitting files in size sum of i.e. 10MB is no problem, but transferring i.e. 10GB often resulted in Nautilus hanging itself up and remaining there in need of `ps -e | grep nautilus` -> `kill -9 <pid>`. I also tested the same thing with Nemo and Caja. While Nemo tends to be more stable than the two others, it still is not perfect and also breaks from time to time. FileZilla is extremely stable, never really got it to break, but it is not very flexible due to the mentioned fact that it can only connect to a single SSH server.

Of course I could also mount a folder with `sshfs`, but this is kind of an inconvenient solution. Too much pre-work to do to get a simple transfer running.

Is there any app that can handle transfers between two SSH servers without breaking? Perfect would be something like FileZilla, that picks up the job again if the connection got interrupted.

Comment: Not an answer because this is not a software recommendation site, but I've been using the (commercial) Beyond Compare (https://www.scootersoftware.com/) for years, and it's just great for this kind of task. It offers two windows, both of which can show a local path or an sftp:// URL, will show the differences between folders, and its ability to copy just the differences makes an excellent resume-mechanism if it breaks, which happens very rarely in my experience. (Not afflilated with them except being a satisfied customer).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are on an Ubuntu version that is still supported, then 
your [`scp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/scp.1.html) command will provide the `-3` switch which enables
copying files from *remote1* to *remote2* via *localhost*:

```
me@local:~> scp -3 user1@remote1:/path/to/file1 user2@remote2:/path/to/file2
```

You can also omit the `-3` switch, but then you will need the
public key (`id_rsa.pub`) of `user1@remote1` in the 
file `authorized_keys` of `user2@remote2`:

```
me@local:~> scp user1@remote1:/path/to/file1 user2@remote2:/path/to/file2
```

`scp` then under the hood does a `ssh user1@remote1` first and from there
`scp /path/to/file1 user2@remote2:/path/to/file2`. That's why the credential must be
distributed different from the `-3` solution.

In other words:

- `scp -3 remote1:file1 remote2:file2` transfers the file from 
  *remote1* to *localhost* and then back to *remote2*. 
  The data travels ***remote1 → localhost → remote2***.
  The *localhost* is the 3rd party in this scenario, hence `-3`.
  For this to work, you will need the credentials from *localhost*
  on both *remote1* and *remote2* because *localhost* connects
  to both of them.
- `scp remote1:file1 remote2:file2` copies the file directly from 
  *remote1* to *remote2* at the speed with wich they are connected
  to each other. *localhost* is not involved here (besides issuing
  the command).
  The data travels ***remote1 → remote2***.
  For this to work, you will need the credentials from *localhost*
  only on *remote1* ***but*** additionally you need the credentials
  of *remote1* on *remote2* because *localhost* connects to *remote1*
  only and then *remote1* connects to *remote2*.

If possible I would choose the second approach. As some comments already
say: <s>usually</s> often the network cable between *remote1* and *remote2* is
far thicker than the cable between them and *localhost*.

Comment: That's just beautiful. ssh is the Swiss army knife of software.  Thanks, I learned something.

Comment: Note that this approach, like the nautilus approach described in the question, will transfer the file first to the local machine, then up to the second server. This will cause significant slowdown when the two remote servers have a faster link between them than the local machine does to either. (For example, when the remote servers are in datacentres and the local machine has a DSL connection.)

Comment: @Stobor Good point, thank you. I updated my answer to clarify a bit how the data travels with and without the `-3`.

Comment: Would the second method work with agent forwarding, without having any key or password on remote1?

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm afraid I cannot tell. I have no real exerience with agent forwarding. But I doubt it because remote1 is supposed to deny access when neither key nor password are supplied, isn't it?

Comment: @PerlDuck: If I understand correctly, it goes like this : key on localhost, agent on localhost, agent forwarding on remote1, no key or agent on remote 1 or 2. It should allow to connect to remote2 from remote1 without needing to trust remote1.

Comment: @EricDuminil yes, this is one of the usecases for which agent-forwarding is supposed to work.

Answer (score 10):

In most cases, two ssh servers can reach each other (or at least one can reach the other), and again in most cases the workstation's internet is far worse than either of the servers.

If so, ordering one server to transfer to the other one is the way to go.

```
ssh server1 nohup scp somefile server2:somefile
```

Check `nohup.out` on server1 for errors.

If server reachability is the other way around you can reverse which machine is the master:

```
ssh server2 nohup scp server1:somefile somefile
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you could use one of several GUI front-ends to rsync:

[Is there any GUI application for command rsync?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514963/is-there-any-gui-application-for-command-rsync)

Or perhaps you could use rsync directly from the command line to connect to both remote servers:

["How to rsync files between two remotes"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes)

I often log in to one server with ssh, then from that server's command line [use rsync to push or pull files to the other remote server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync) -- that's generally much quicker than trying to transfer the files through some 3rd computer.

The rsync is smart enough to do some work, then if anything goes wrong and interrupts the process, it can later resume right where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SCP protocol.
    `scp file you want to transfer login@address_of_second_server:/path_where_you_want_to_save`

Comment: OP wants to copy files between two remote computers, not from local computer to remote computer. He also seems to be looking for a GUI solution.

Comment: @user68186 my answer is valid.